# What has higher water flow? A 10 inches BB or a 20 inches SL?

Tags: water

What do you think has higher water flow? A 20 inches tall Slim Line Sediment Filter (with 2.5 inches sediment filter diameter inside) or a 10 inches tall Big Blue Sediment Filter (with 4.5 inches sediment filter diameter inside) assuming for sake of comparison both filters inside is 5 micron?

A 10 inches Big Blue
[image]

A 20 inches Slim filter
[image]

Comment: I would be more interesed in filtering efficiency.

Comment: what you mean by filtering efficiency? of course my question involves what will happen if the filter is clogged. what do you think will have higher flow if filter is clogged.. or which do you think is more efficient? and what is filtering efficiency?

Comment: What do you expect from the filter - the difference in ppm before and after. What do you think clogged means - could be flow = 0... but that also depends on input pressure.

Comment: @Jtl ... `my question involves what will happen if the filter is clogged` ... your question does not ask that at all

Comment: Have you asked the 2 manufacturers (or looked on their web site) what their claimed flow rates are?

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, and using the numbers provided, not the actual sizes. The slimline filter has marginally more surface area, so it might be slightly faster flowing.

If flow rate is important install two filters side by side and you will get double the flow rate.

Comment: Have you computed the surface area of both? So the slimline has more surface area? How about filter area? does it have more filter internal space being 4.5 inches?

Comment: for computing I did length times width, (and ignored the constant pi)   The internal bore just needs to be 3/4" or whatever size your pipes are  I don't expect the two different models to vary in performance by much.